# Error while trying to clone the git repo through jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I installed both git and Jenkins on the same server. while trying to clone the repository through Jenkins I am facing the below issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.

`stderr: No ECDSA host key is known for 192.168.1.244 and you have requested strict checking. Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Answer (score 1):

Using the same account '`user`' as the one running Jenkins, try a `ssh -Ti /path/to/private/key user@server`.

It should ask (one time only) a question like:

```
The authenticity of host '[hostname] ([IP address])' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is [key fingerprint].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Answer yes, and Jenkins should not block anymore on this step.